# VSCode - How to check list of all commands for a specific extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Basically I use shortcuts to compile & run code, which was easy to set for PHP Debug extension. I just searched for the "debug php" (Ctrl+Shift+P) and it showed there is a command with php.debug.debugPhpFile identificator. So I just added following to keybindings.json & it works perfectly:

```
{
"key": "ctrl+f5",
"command": "php.debug.debugPhpFile"
},
```

I was trying to do the same with "Debugger for Java" extension, but search doesn't show the specific command for compiling and running my code. I only found "Force Compile" option which basically useless when I need not to just compile my code into .class, but also to run it & see the output. There is a button coming with this extension named "Run Java", it does it's job but I need a shortcut option.

So what I have? workbench.action.debug.run which only opens debugger & java.workspace.compile which only compiles to .class I guess? It would be fine if I just somehow get the list of all commands for this extension, and there is something like java.workspace.class.run or java.workspace.run etc. (Ctrl + space doesn't really show what I need).

Would appreciate the answers & thoughts, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All commands for specific extension should be listed in the "Feature Contributions" tab of its details page.

[image: Debugger for Java extension details page showing expanded "Commands" section with first few command codes]